# tic tac toe in java processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm currently working on a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game in Processing, and I'm having trouble with two aspects:

Placement Issue:
The X and O symbols are not being placed correctly on the grid. The placements seem to be randomized, and I'm unsure why. Whenever I click on a box it doesn't seem to place in that coordinated box

Mouse Clicks Issue:
I have set up the left-click to place X and right-click to place O, but it doesn't seem to be working as intended.

Here is my current code:

```
// Declare a 3x3 grid of TicTacToeBox objects
TicTacToeBox[][] grid = new TicTacToeBox[3][3];

// gameStatus:
// 0 - Display Home screen
// 1 - Display Tic Tac Toe grid
// 2 - Display Game over screen
int gameStatus = 0;

// Determine which player's turn it is 
int currentPlayer = 1;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  displayHomeScreen();
}

void draw() {
  // Draw the appropriate screen based on gameStatus
  if (gameStatus == 1) {
    background(255);
    displayGrid();
  } else if (gameStatus == 2) {
    background(0);
    displayGameOver();
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  // Check the gameStatus and respond to mouse clicks accordingly
  if (gameStatus == 1) {
    float boxSize = width / 3.0;
    int col = floor(mouseX / boxSize);
    int row = floor(mouseY / boxSize);

    // Check if the box is valid and empty
    if (isValidBox(row, col) && grid[row][col].symbol == ' ') {
      // Place X or O based on the mouse button and currentPlayer
      if (mouseButton == LEFT && currentPlayer == 1) {
        grid[row][col].symbol = 'X';
        currentPlayer = 2;
      } else if (mouseButton == RIGHT && currentPlayer == 2) {
        grid[row][col].symbol = 'O';
        currentPlayer = 1;
      }
    }
  } else if (gameStatus == 0 && mouseX > 250 && mouseX < 350 && mouseY > 250 && mouseY < 300) {
    // Transition to the game screen when PLAY is clicked
    gameStatus = 1;
  }
}

void displayGrid() {
  float boxSize = width / 3.0;

  // Loop through the grid and draw each TicTacToeBox
  for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
      if (grid[row][col] == null) {
        grid[row][col] = new TicTacToeBox(row, col, boxSize, ' ');
      }
      grid[row][col].draw();
    }
  }
}

// Check if the row and column are clear to place
boolean isValidBox(int row, int col) {
  return row >= 0 && row < 3 && col >= 0 && col < 3;
}

void displayHomeScreen() {
  // Display the home screen with instructions
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  textAlign(CENTER, TOP);
  textSize(50);
  text("Tic-Tac-Toe", width/2, 100);
  textSize(25);
  fill(0);
  text("Click PLAY to start", width/2, 200);
  noFill();
  rect(250, 250, 100, 50);
  textSize(20);
  fill(0);
  text("PLAY", width/2, 265);
}

void displayGameOver() {
  // Display the game over screen with a prompt to play again
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  textAlign(CENTER, TOP);
  textSize(50);
  text("GAME OVER!", width/2, 100);
  textSize(25);
  fill(0, 0, 255);
  text("CLICK TO PLAY AGAIN", width/2, 200);
}

class TicTacToeBox {
  float x;
  float y;
  float boxSize;
  char symbol = ' ';

  TicTacToeBox(float x, float y, float boxSize, char symbol) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.boxSize = boxSize;
    this.symbol = symbol;
  }

  void draw() {
    stroke(0);
    noFill();
    rect(x * boxSize, y * boxSize, boxSize, boxSize);
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
    textSize(32);
    fill(0);
    float symbolX = x * boxSize + boxSize/2;
    float symbolY = y * boxSize + boxSize/2;
    text(symbol, symbolX, symbolY);
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to remove the 'java' tag since this is primarily Processing code.

Answer (score -1):

The following source code demonstrates creating a 3x3 grid using a Rect class array to keep track of mouse presses. Perhaps a similar technique can be used in your game.

```
Rect[] r;

final int _numCols = 3;
final int _numRows = 3;

final int _wndW = 400;
final int _wndH = 400;

class Rect {
  int x, y, w, h;
  boolean leftPressed = false;
  boolean rightPressed = false;

  // Constructor
  Rect(int xpos, int ypos, int wide, int ht) {
    x = xpos;
    y = ypos;
    w = wide;
    h = ht;
  }

  void display(int id) {
    fill(255); // background color
    rect(x, y, w, h);
    fill(0); // text color
    textSize(18);
    text(str(id), x + w - 18, y + 18);
  }
}

void rectGrid(int left, int top, int w, int h, int vg, int hg) {
  int id = 0;
  // build by row
  for (int k = 0; k < _numRows; k++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < _numCols; j++) {
      int x = left + j*(w+vg);
      int y = top + k*(h+hg);
      r[id] = new Rect(x, y, w, h);
      id++;
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  size(_wndW, _wndH);
  background(0, 0, 245);
  r = new Rect[_numRows*_numCols];
  rectGrid(0, 0, _wndW/_numCols, _wndH/_numRows, 0, 0);
}

void draw() {
  for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
    r[i].display(i); // Display each object
    if (r[i].leftPressed == true) {
      text("X", r[i].x + r[i].w/2, r[i].y + r[i].h/2);
    }
    if (r[i].rightPressed == true) {
      text("O", r[i].x + r[i].w/2, r[i].y + r[i].h/2);
    }
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
    if ((mouseX >= r[i].x) && (mouseX <= r[i].x +r[i].w) && (mouseY >= r[i].y) && (mouseY <= r[i].y + r[i].h)) {
      println("id =", i);
      if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
        r[i].leftPressed = true;
      }
      if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
        r[i].rightPressed = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Suggestions:**
You don't need a two dimensional array for your grid; a one dimensional array works just fine and is less complicated.  I would add two booleans to your grid class (leftPressed and rightPressed) and delete the symbol parameter.  The 'draw()' method of the grid class should probably be renamed to something like 'display()' since 'draw' is a keyword in Processing and will avoid confusion.  The methods displayGrid() and isValidBox() can be safely removed with the technique shown below.  The main code change should be in mousePressed() since this wasn't working correctly.  Looping through each box in the grid will trap the mouse button click correctly, then at this point you can check whether it was the right or left mouseButton which was clicked and the corresponding boolean can be set to 'true'.  The main 'draw()' will then use this information to draw either an 'X' or an 'O'.  I know it sounds like a lot, but these changes are one solution to your problems.  Your revised source code is shown below:

```
// Declare a 3x3 grid of TicTacToeBox objects
Grid[] g = new Grid[9];

// gameStatus:
// 0 - Display Home screen
// 1 - Display Tic Tac Toe grid
// 2 - Display Game over screen
int gameStatus = 0;

// Determine which player's turn it is
int currentPlayer = 1;

class Grid {
  float x;
  float y;
  float boxSize;
  boolean leftPressed = false;
  boolean rightPressed = false;

  Grid(float x, float y, float boxSize) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.boxSize = boxSize;
  }

  void display() {
    stroke(0);
    noFill();
    rect(x, y, boxSize, boxSize);
  }
}

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  displayHomeScreen();
  // initialize array
  float boxSize = width / 3.0;
  int id = 0;
  for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      float x = j*boxSize;
      float y = k*boxSize;
      g[id] = new Grid(x, y, boxSize);
      id++;
    }
  }
}

void draw() {
  // Draw the appropriate screen based on gameStatus
  if (gameStatus == 1) {
    background(255);
    for (int i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
      g[i].display(); // Display each object
      if (g[i].leftPressed == true) {
        text("X", g[i].x + g[i].boxSize/2, g[i].y + g[i].boxSize/2);
      }
      if (g[i].rightPressed == true) {
        text("O", g[i].x + g[i].boxSize/2, g[i].y + g[i].boxSize/2);
      }
    }
  } else if (gameStatus == 2) {
    background(0);
    displayGameOver();
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  // Check the gameStatus and respond to mouse clicks accordingly
  if (gameStatus == 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
      if ((mouseX >= g[i].x) && (mouseX <= g[i].x +g[i].boxSize) && (mouseY >= g[i].y) && (mouseY <= g[i].y + g[i].boxSize)) {
        println("id =", i);
        if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
          g[i].leftPressed = true;
        }
        if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
          g[i].rightPressed = true;
        }
      }
    }
  } else if (gameStatus == 0 && mouseX > 250 && mouseX < 350 && mouseY > 250 && mouseY < 300) {
    // Transition to the game screen when PLAY is clicked
    gameStatus = 1;
  }
}

void displayHomeScreen() {
  // Display the home screen with instructions
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  textAlign(CENTER, TOP);
  textSize(50);
  text("Tic-Tac-Toe", width/2, 100);
  textSize(25);
  fill(0);
  text("Click PLAY to start", width/2, 200);
  noFill();
  rect(250, 250, 100, 50);
  textSize(20);
  fill(0);
  text("PLAY", width/2, 265);
}

void displayGameOver() {
  // Display the game over screen with a prompt to play again
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  textAlign(CENTER, TOP);
  textSize(50);
  text("GAME OVER!", width/2, 100);
  textSize(25);
  fill(0, 0, 255);
  text("CLICK TO PLAY AGAIN", width/2, 200);
}
```